# How to effectively reduce the length of input to mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

My data has 20 fields in the schema. Only the first three fields are important to me as far as my map reduce program is concerned. How can I decrease the size of input to mapper so that only the first three fields are received.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...20 columns in schema.
I want only 1,2,3 in the mapper to process it as offset and value.
```

NOTE I cant use PIG as some other map reduce logic is implemented in MAP REDUCE.

Comment: which api u r using - mapred or the new ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom `RecordReader` to do this :

```
public class TrimmedRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
   private LineRecordReader lineReader;
   private LongWritable lineKey;
   private Text lineValue;

   public TrimmedRecordReader(JobConf job, FileSplit split) throws IOException {
      lineReader = new LineRecordReader(job, split);
      lineKey = lineReader.createKey();
      lineValue = lineReader.createValue();
   }

   public boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
      if (!lineReader.next(lineKey, lineValue)) {
          return false;
      }

      String[] fields = lineValue.toString().split(",");
      if (fields.length < 3) {
          throw new IOException("Invalid record received");
      }
      value.set(fields[0] + "," + fields[1] + "," + fields[2]);
      return true;
   }

   public LongWritable createKey() {
      return lineReader.createKey();
   }

   public Text createValue() {
      return lineReader.createValue();
   }

   public long getPos() throws IOException {
      return lineReader.getPos();
   }

   public void close() throws IOException {
      lineReader.close();
   }

   public float getProgress() throws IOException {
      return lineReader.getProgress();
   }
}
```

It should be pretty self-explanatory, just a wrap up of `LineRecordReader`. 
Unfortunately, to invoke it you need to extend the `InputFormat` too. The following is enough :

```
public class TrimmedTextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> {

   public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit input,
     JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        reporter.setStatus(input.toString());
        return new TrimmedRecordReader(job, (FileSplit) input);
   }
}
```

Just don't forget to set it in the driver.

Comment: thanks blackSmith for the code.. I already did the code and cross checked with your implementation.. :)

Comment: I am yet to check it in the production environment. Will update about it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom input format in map reduce to read the required fields alone.

Just for reference, following blog post explains how to read text as Paragraphs

http://blog.minjar.com/post/54759039969/mapreduce-custom-input-formats-reading

Comment: thanks for the article Vijay. I will try to implement it for my use case.